# How do I tokenize this string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, tokenize, text-parsing

I have this string:

```
%{Children^10 Health "sanitation management"^5}
```

And I want to convert it to tokenize this into an array of hashes:

```
[{:keywords=>"children", :boost=>10}, {:keywords=>"health", :boost=>nil}, {:keywords=>"sanitation management", :boost=>5}]
```

I'm aware of StringScanner and the [Syntax gem](http://syntax.rubyforge.org/) but I can't find enough code examples for both.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a real language, a lexer's the way to go - [like Guss said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713559/how-do-i-tokenize-this-string-in-ruby/713608#713608).  But if the full language is only as complicated as your example, you can use this quick hack:

```
irb> text = %{Children^10 Health "sanitation management"^5}
irb> text.scan(/(?:(\w+)|"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)")(?:\^(\d+))?/).map do |word,phrase,boost|
       { :keywords => (word || phrase).downcase, :boost => (boost.nil? ? nil : boost.to_i) }
     end
#=> [{:boost=>10, :keywords=>"children"}, {:boost=>nil, :keywords=>"health"}, {:boost=>5, :keywords=>"sanitation management"}]
```

If you're trying to parse a regular language then this method will suffice - though it wouldn't take many more complications to make the language non-regular.

A quick breakdown of the regex:

- `\w+` matches any single-term keywords
- `(?:\\.|[^\\"]])*` uses non-capturing parentheses (`(?:...)`) to match the contents of an escaped double quoted string - either an escaped symbol (`\n`, `\"`, `\\`, etc.) or any single character that's not an escape symbol or an end quote.
- `"((?:\\.|[^\\"]])*)"` captures only the contents of a quoted keyword phrase.
- `(?:(\w+)|"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)")` matches any keyword - single term or phrase, capturing single terms into `$1` and phrase contents into `$2`
- `\d+` matches a number.
- `\^(\d+)` captures a number following a caret (`^`).  Since this is the third set of capturing parentheses, it will be caputred into `$3`.
- `(?:\^(\d+))?` captures a number following a caret if it's there, matches the empty string otherwise.

`String#scan(regex)` matches the regex against the string as many times as possible, outputing an array of "matches".  If the regex contains capturing parens, a "match" is an array of items captured - so `$1` becomes `match[0]`, `$2` becomes `match[1]`, etc.  Any capturing parenthesis that doesn't get matched against part of the string maps to a `nil` entry in the resulting "match".

The `#map` then takes these matches, uses some block magic to break each captured term into different variables (we could have done `do |match| ; word,phrase,boost = *match`), and then creates your desired hashes.  Exactly one of `word` or `phrase` will be `nil`, since both can't be matched against the input, so `(word || phrase)` will return the non-`nil` one, and `#downcase` will convert it to all lowercase.  `boost.to_i` will convert a string to an integer while `(boost.nil? ? nil : boost.to_i)` will ensure that `nil` boosts stay `nil`.

Comment: If I were using it in code, I'd probably use //x and add comments in place.

Comment: If it were possible I'd give you two upvotes.  1 for the pragmatic approach, and one for the well-described regex.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a non-robust example using `StringScanner`.  This is code I just adapted from [Ruby Quiz: Parsing JSON](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz155.html), which has an excellent explanation.

```
require 'strscan'

def test_parse
  text = %{Children^10 Health "sanitation management"^5}
  expected = [{:keywords=>"children", :boost=>10}, {:keywords=>"health", :boost=>nil}, {:keywords=>"sanitation management", :boost=>5}]


  assert_equal(expected, parse(text))
end

def parse(text)
  @input = StringScanner.new(text)

  output = []

  while keyword = parse_string || parse_quoted_string
    output << {
      :keywords => keyword,
      :boost => parse_boost
    }
    trim_space
  end

  output
end

def parse_string
  if @input.scan(/\w+/)
    @input.matched.downcase
  else
    nil
  end
end

def parse_quoted_string
  if @input.scan(/"/)
    str = parse_quoted_contents
    @input.scan(/"/) or raise "unclosed string"
    str
  else
    nil
  end
end

def parse_quoted_contents
  @input.scan(/[^\\"]+/) and @input.matched
end

def parse_boost
  if @input.scan(/\^/)
    boost = @input.scan(/\d+/)
    raise 'missing boost value' if boost.nil?
    boost.to_i
  else
    nil
  end
end

def trim_space
  @input.scan(/\s+/)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is an arbitrary grammar, and to parse it what you really want is a lexer - you can write a grammar file that described your syntax and then use the lexer to generate a recursive parser from your grammar.

Writing a lexer (or even a recursive parser) is not really trivial - although it is a useful exercise in programming - but you can find a list of Ruby lexers/parsers in this email message here: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.ruby/2005-11/msg02233.html

RACC is available as a standard module of Ruby 1.8, so I suggest you concentrate on that even if its manual is not really easy to follow and it requires familiarity with yacc.